# Select rows in a table which aren't in another one with a nullable foreign key

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, select, android-sqlite

I have the following database to use it in an Android 3.0 tablet application.

[image]

I want to select every Defect which it isn't on `EReportDefect`. As you can see `EReportDefect.defectId` **could be null**.

This select returns 0 rows. But there are defects which aren't on `EReportDefect` table.

```
SELECT 
  Defect.defectId,
  Defect.description
FROM 
  Defect 
WHERE 
   qapId = ? AND
   defectId NOT IN 
     (SELECT defectId FROM EReportDefect WHERE eReportId = ?);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I make works:

```
SELECT
   Defect.defectId,
   Defect.description
FROM
   Defect
WHERE
   qapId = ? AND
   defectId NOT IN 
     (SELECT
        defectId
      FROM
        EReportDefect
      WHERE eReportId = ? AND defectId IS NOT NULL);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can join both table on column `defectID` using `LEFT JOIN`,

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    Defect a
        LEFT JOIN EReportDefect b
            ON a.defectID = b.defectID
WHERE   b.defectID IS NULL
```

`b.defectID` will have `NULL` values if it has no match on `a.defectID`.

**UPDATE 1**

```
SELECT a.*
FROM    Defect a
        LEFT JOIN EReportDefect b
            ON a.defectID = b.defectID
WHERE  b.defectID IS NULL AND
        a.qapID = ? 
       -- AND b.ReportID = ?
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm going to use it on a SQLite 3 database on an Android application. Will it work on SQLite 3?

Comment: And also I need to pass qapId and eReportId values. How can I do it?

Comment: @VansFannel I think `b.ReportID = ?` is already unreachable since it will always have `null` value if `DefectID` on Defects table is not present on EreportDefect.

Comment: @VansFannel if you need to pass in qapId and eReportId would that not possibly prevent the sql from returning every defect not in the other table?

Comment: `a.qapID` can still be on condition but adding `b.ReportID` will always return zero result.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe I am missing something but to me it seems if you remove "qapId = ? AND" and "WHERE eReportId = ?" it should just return results where there is not an entry in EReportDefect table

```
SELECT 
  Defect.defectId,
  Defect.description
FROM 
  Defect 
WHERE 
   defectId NOT IN 
     (SELECT defectId FROM EReportDefect);
```